# How can I convert a 5 digit int date and 7 digit int time to a real date?

Tags: date, language-agnostic

I've come across some data where the date for today's value is `77026` and the time (as of a few minutes ago) is `4766011`. FYI: today is `Fri, 18 Nov 2011 12:54:46 -0600`

I can't figure out how these represent a date/time, and there is no supporting documentation.

How can I convert these numbers to a date value?

---

Some other dates from today are:

```
77026 | 4765509
77026 | 4765003
77026 | 4714129
77026 | 4617107
```

And some dates from what is *probably* yesterday:

```
77025 | 6292509
77025 | 6238790
77025 | 4009544
```

Comment: It is impossible to find out the logic from a single isolated example. If you had a table of such examples, it is a different matter. If you are lucky, this might look familiar to someone here, but that might not happen.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what yesterday at the exact same time was?  (BTW: Don't think this belongs here really, but it seems interesting :>)

Comment: @oded I added some dates for you. Let me know if you think I should provide more.

Comment: @user24601 I won't be able to get an exact time, but I did add some more date/times, hopefully they'll be useful. p.s., you should set up a username :-p

Comment: Well, at least when it comes to dates, it _looks_ like a count up from some epoch (which is a hypothesis you could calculate and test). With the time - does it reset every day? Do you have any examples of what time any of them represents?

Comment: Well, if 77026 is treated as a day number, that'd give us an epoch sometime in the 1800s. 4766011 could be centi-seconds since midnight. but without more examples, impossible to say either way.

Comment: @Oded, `77026 | 4766011` should be within the last half-hour. Other than that, I don't have any more recent info on the data (yet, I'm polling for updated data every minute now).

Comment: @MarcB I added 7 other dates since my original post, did you see those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, with your expanded examples, it would appear the first number is a day count. That'd put this time system's epoch at

```
to_days(today) = 734824
734824 - 77025 = 657799
from_days(657799) = Dec 29, 1800
```

The time values are problematic, it looks like they're decreasing (unless you listed most recent first?), but if they are some "# of intervals since midnight", then centi-seconds could be likely. That'd give us a range of 0 - 8,640,000.

```
4765509 = 47655.09 seconds -> sec_to_time(47655) = 13:14:15
sec_to_time(47650.03) -> 13:14:10
sec_to_time(47141.29) -> 13:05:41
sec_to_time(46171.07) -> 12:49:31
```

Comment: Thanks. The time values are increasing, BTW

Comment: Looks like everything is converting perfectly! Thanks